Are the writings of Eusebius controversial?
I am reading "The History of the Church".  I have thus far read a supposed letter from Christ himself written to an official, and a declaration that Christ descended into Hades following his Crucifixion (an idea which I think is accepted by some denominations, and rejected by others).
Are these writings considered generally credible?  I find it hard to believe that an actual letter from Christ would not be more well-known and revered, should it be accepted as legit.

I wouldn't say his works are actually controversial, but they aren't generally read as infallible either. As far as I've read that letter to and from Christ to the king is regarded as spurious by nearly everyone. I think some ancient Syrian churches included it in their liturgy but that's about it.
As for Eusebius' writings as a whole, I'll quote a paragraph from Schaff on the value of his history.

Of his works, the historical are by far the most celebrated and the most valuable; to wit, his Ecclesiastical History, his Chronicle, his Life of Constantine, and a tract on the Martyrs of Palestine in the Diocletian persecution. The position of Eusebius, at the close of the period of persecution, and in the opening of the period of the imperial establishment of Christianity, and his employment of many ancient documents, some of which have since been lost, give these works a peculiar value. He is temperate, upon the whole, impartial, and truth-loving—rare virtues in an age of intense excitement and polemical zeal like that in which he lived. The fact that he was the first to work this important field of theological study, and for many centuries remained a model in it, justly entitles him to his honorable distinction of Father of Church History. Yet he is neither a critical student nor an elegant writer of history, but only a diligent and learned collector. His Ecclesiastical History, from the birth of Christ to the victory of Constantine over Licinius in 324, gives a colorless, defective, incoherent, fragmentary, yet interesting picture of the heroic youth of the church, and owes its incalculable value, not to the historic art of the author, but almost entirely to his copious and mostly literal extracts from foreign, and in some cases now extinct, sources. As concerns the first three centuries, too, it stands alone; for the successors of Eusebius begin their history where he leaves off.


Are the writings of Eusibius controversial?
In general, the writings of Eusebius are held in high esteem.
The fact that Eusebius wrote that a supposed letter from Christ himself written to an official existed, is simply that. He wrote in his History of the Church that such a document apparently was held to known by some individuals of the Early Church. He never made claims that the letter was authentic.
